# How to include a header in every router.put or router.post call?

Tags: reactjs, express, http

I would like to have a header included in every router.put or router.post call. Currently I have a router.put call that contains the following logic:

```
router.put('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    const { body } = req
    const { authorization } = req.headers
    const options = {
        url: `${request_url}/saveconfig/`,
        json: true,
        body: body,
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'authorization': authorization
        }
    }

    try {
        let response = await httpRequest(options)
        res.status(response.statusCode).send(response.body)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error)
    }
})
```

But I have about 50 other router.put or router.post calls that I would like to include the `authorization: authorization` header. Is there a way in React or some other way to make it so that every router.put or router.post contains this header?

Comment: Sorry but, where is `router` coming from? which lib are you using to make requests?

Comment: const router = express.Router()

Comment: What about the lib for your requests?

Comment: Have you considered using a [`router.use`](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#router.use) middleware function. You can see wether us a PUT or POST request by looking at the value of [`req.method`](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.method)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can take advantage of the `router.use` method to add a new middleware function that will create the `options` object on the `req` object if the request is of type `POST` or `PUT`.

Using your example, you could do something like this:

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.method === "POST" || req.method === "PUT") {
    const { body } = req;
    const { authorization } = req.headers;
    req.options = {
      url: `${request_url}/saveconfig/`,
      json: true,
      body: body,
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        authorization: authorization
      }
    };
  }

  next();
});

router.put("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let response = await httpRequest(req.options);
    res.status(response.statusCode).send(response.body);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error);
  }
});
```

Documentation:
https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#router.use
https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.method

Comment: I have router.put and router.post in other files, where can I throw this router.use? Would I just throw it in my app.js?

Comment: You can put it wherever you want. Even on the `Express.app` definition. The higher it is the most it will affect. It's hard to recommend a place without knowing the project structure.